# ERROR! Error: The entity generator doesn't support reactive apps at the moment

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I am getting "ERROR! Error: The entity generator doesn't support reactive apps at the moment" error while generating entity in jhipster 6.8.0 with reactive gateway. What is the work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JHipster entity subgenerator will support reactive apps in the next release, v6.9.0.

Support for MongoDB, Cassandra, Couchbase databases was implemented [in this pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11416).

Support for SQL databases was implemented in [this pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11742), which is also planned for v6.9.0.

If you want to test out the entity generator support for reactive apps today, you can use the master branch (or the above PR for SQL) of `generator-jhipster`. Follow the [Contributing guide](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/be9af32aa2c5c0d67adc8a73528fa87acd908ef6/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup) to use a local version of the generator.  Note that things may change before the next release, and using the master branch will require manual upgrade when a release is made (versus using the `upgrade` subgenerator).

Comment: Too bad postgresql is not supported yet :(